# Do not fill the space more div

Tags: html, css

i have this code

```
<div id="menu_right_levels">
    <div class="level"> Livello 1 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 2 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 3 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 4 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 5 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 6 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 7 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 8 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 9 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 10 </div>
</div>
```

And this Style

```
 .level {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

I need a responsive div who auto fill him and have the same height, i don't know what, but my 10 divs, with height:10% appear so:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the border: Every div is in fact **10% + 2px** tall. What you need is the CSS `box-sizing` property. With `box-sizing: border-box;` the CSS `height` property is also applied to the **padding and border**.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q39vvzfv/

```js
var boxSizing = "border-box";
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("level");
function toggleBoxSizing(e) {
 if (boxSizing == "border-box") {
   boxSizing = "content-box";
    e.target.innerHTML = "Enable box-sizing";
  } else {
   boxSizing = "border-box";
    e.target.innerHTML = "Disable box-sizing";
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
   els[i].style.boxSizing = boxSizing;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#orange {
  background-color: #FF4500;
  height: 940px;
}
#menu_right_levels {
  float: right;
  height: 940px;
  width: 380px;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
}
.level {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<div id="menu_right_levels">
    <div class="level"> Livello 1 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 2 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 3 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 4 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 5 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 6 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 7 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 8 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 9 </div>
    <div class="level"> Livello 10 </div>
</div>
<div id="orange">
  <button onclick="toggleBoxSizing(event)">Disable box-sizing</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your borders. Every div is essentially 10% + 2px tall. The 2px adds up (adds up to 20px to be exact).

A simple solution would be to add padding to the red div to make up for the extra 20 pixels:

```css
#container {
  height: 600px
}
#left {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 20px; /* BOTTOM PADDING ADDED */
}
#menu_right_levels {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%
}
.level {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>

  <div id="menu_right_levels">
    <div class="level">Livello 1</div>
    <div class="level">Livello 2</div>
    <div class="level">Livello 3</div>
    <div class="level">Livello 4</div>
    <div class="level">Livello 5</div>
    <div class="level">Livello 6</div>
    <div class="level">Livello 7</div>
    <div class="level">Livello 8</div>
    <div class="level">Livello 9</div>
    <div class="level">Livello 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: box-sizing should be used here, so no need to mind about border-size, or eventual padding ...